# Suggestions to improve single letter recognition from 28 x 28 px images

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I currently have 28 by 28 images and I'm trying to take each letter out and run them through a character recognition neural network: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8M88.png). Here's the code I'm using to do this:

```
for user in users:

for i in range(IMAGES):
    imagePath = user + "/" + str(i+1) + ".png"

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
    im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im_bw,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)

    i=0
    for cnt in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.imwrite(user+"/letter"+str(i)+".png",thresh1[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        i=i+1
```

As you can tell from the image I linked ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8M88.png)), this isn't happening incredibly efficiently. I know it's probably likely due to the incredibly low resolution, but does anyone have any suggestions for improving this? The context behind this, since someone might recommend I use an image to string thing like tesseract, is I'm trying to go through the words and multilabel each letter with what letter it is and what user it belongs to in order to come up with like a dataset of user letters to give to a neural network.

28 x 28 px Image examples: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3AYw.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIe8w.png)

Comment: If you have some 28x28 pixel images, please show them. At the moment you are showing us a single 920x574 pixel image of some images of varying sizes. You also say you are doing some machine learning but I can't see that in your code. You also talk about assigning to users but it is not clear to me why.

Comment: I'll add some of the images. The goal of the project is to identify and differentiate handwriting between users. My idea is that if I take what the user writes, break it up, and use a convolutional neural network to label and identify whether each letter belongs to which user. I didn't upload the code for the machine learning because that wasn't what I having a problem with. I'll upload some 28 x 28 image examples.